# Sending and releasing multiple keys at once using AutoHotkey

Tags: autohotkey

I'm attempting to send three keys (Alt, Shift, Q) at same time using this script:

```
:*:pk::   ;
Send, {AltDown}{ShiftDown}{qDown}
return
```

When I run this is it does not release the keys, it seems like the Alt button remains pressed. After the above keys are pressed I then want to press the "q" character again (separately, not at same time).

How can I amend my script above to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using `Down`, you must also send an `Up` to the same key or else it will remain pressed. This can be achieved like this:

```
:*:pk::
    Send, {Alt Down}{Shift Down}{q Down}{Alt Up}{Shift Up}{q Up}
    Send, {q}
```

Comment: I think `Send, !+q` would be just as fine.